# Google PageRank - How important is it?

Tags: seo, pagerank

We're just trying to optimise our SEO procedures and have read about Google pageranking not being a factor these days.

But does that mean that a link from a site with a pagerank of 0 is going have the same impact as a link from a site with a pagerank of 3?

Comment: [This study](http://royal.pingdom.com/2010/01/14/how-important-is-google-pagerank-to-site-success/) concluded that PageRank still matters, even if it is moderately less important now than it perhaps used to be. Definitely worth a read.

Comment: PageRank means NOTHING, only PigeonRank matters now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PageRank](http://www.google.com/corporate/tech.html) is still a big factor in organic search result listings. It's a quick assessment of where you stand, but it is definitely only part of the picture. And, in my SEO experience trying to build smaller sites in the PR4 range, you do far better getting 5 or 10 inbound links from sites PR6 or even 5, than hundreds from nothing sites at PR1 or even 3.

In my experience (which is mostly e-commerce, btw), getting a startup site into that 4 range is critical, and it does take time. SEO is best approached from the standpoint of getting into the right search results, than trying to always be first or second in the results. As long as your pages contain relevant, fresh content, you'll be on your way to make that happen.

ps/btw: This question is probably better put onto one of the other sites, since this is a technical programming forum.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds radical, but I would say Google PR is dead. And long live the UE(user experience), if Google is capable enough to discrete it at all.

Because of PR, so many people are crazy about link building. Those madness produced lot of link farms and useless sites and blogs just for links, and the rampant spamming partially because of it.

Link is only useful when visitors to that web site have a big possibility to find useful stuff though visiting lined sites. Otherwise, it do not make any sense at all.

However, as far as I know, Google PR does not smart enough to rule out useless links. That is the reason that so many people drove into Google PR rush, rather than think about what users really like.

Ad rules of thumb, pay more attention to your visitors. Providing useful info, fresh content, and clean, semantically sound HTML, css, and js. I am sure you will be fine eventually.

By the way, Google made a statement months ago that they will abandon PR, for ever. Hurray!

Answer (score 0):

Google created a ghost called PageRank, 
tried to barter with users in exchange of data, 
went out of hand
& now trying hard to kill it.
PageRank is partially responsible for spoiling the web

Answer (score 0):

PageRank is Google's way of measuring the authority of your website.

However, it does not always help how your site ranks for certain keywords.

E.g. if your keyword was something like "movie reviews", you would get better positions having your website linked from 5 low pageranked "movie review" sites compared to 5 high but irrelevant pageranked sites.

My advice would be not to chase pagerank, but to build backlinks from sites relevant to yours. Avoid "bad neighborhoods", sites that are not moderated with massive amounts of spam as Google is getting pretty heavy-handed on these types of websites.